# Trouble with Python scraping with Wunderground API

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm scraping historical weather data in bulk using the Wunderground API. My code works for dates before 1970, but afterwards it returns the following error. What could be going wrong?

```
historical_url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + api_key + "/history_" + year + month + day + \
                "/q/" + state + "/" + city + ".json"

# Pull data from url for given location and date 
f = urllib2.urlopen(historical_url)

# Read the data into JSON object
json_string = f.read()

parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
```

Here is the error:

```
File "/home/svenkatesh/Weather/getdata.py", line 82, in getHistory
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
File "/apps/python27/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/apps/python27/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/apps/python27/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 68: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Tried looking at the `json_string` before jumping in and parsing it?